# If time reverses the Wide Sense Stationary(WSS) preserves or not?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, stationarity, joint-distribution, cross-correlation

If $X(t)$ is WSS with autocorrelation $R_{X}(\tau)$ then is $Y(t)=X(-t)$ WSS? How to find Cross Correaltion of $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ too? And, can we say they are jointly WSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process $X_t$ is WSS when ($K_{XX}$ is an autocovariance function):

$$
\forall\tau\in\mathbb{R}: \mathbb{E}[X_t]=\mathbb{E}[X_{t+\tau}]
$$
$$
\forall t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}:K_{XX}(t_1, t_2)=K_{XX}(t_1-t_2,0)
$$
$$
\forall t\in\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{E}[|X_t|^2] < \infty
$$

You can note, that this definition is symmetric with respect to substitution $t\rightarrow -t$, so inverted process is WSS if and only if the original one is WSS.